# UNITY 3D C# XML MERGE

Tags: c#, xml

what is simplest way to merge two XML file and create new one? I'm using unity and i think it is limited in C# APIs ans references and I'm not professional programmer.

File 1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserData>

  <Data>

  <FIELD1>NAME 1</FIELD1>

  </Data>

</UserData>
```

File 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserData>


  <Data>

  <FIELD2>NAME 2</FIELD2>

  </Data>

</UserData>
```

Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <UserData>

  <Data>

   <FIELD1>NAME 1</FIELD1>      
   <FIELD2>NAME 2</FIELD2>

  </Data>

 </UserData>
```

Comment: Load the two files in to two objects in programming, combine the `Data` field of the two objects in one of them, save the object back out as xml. Hopefully that will get you started, just focus on how to solve each of those 3 steps individually and you will find the problem easier to research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start with making your implementation of UserData more generic, so that it can accept multiple field types instead of field1 and field2, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<UserData>
  <Data>
    <Field>NAME 1</Field>      
    <Field>NAME 2</Field>
  </Data>
</UserData>
```

Your container could then look like this:

```
[XmlRoot("UserData")]
public class UserDataContainer
{
    public UserDataContainer() {...}
    // Can be used load and save a list of strings (Field(s) in XML)
    [XmlArray("Data"), XmlArrayItem("Field"),Type = typeof(string))]
    public List<string> Data = new List<string>();

    public static UserDataContainer Load(path){...}

    public void Save(path){...}

    public List<string> GetFields(){...}

    public void SetFields(List<string> Fields){...}
}
```

If you need help on loading/writing data specifically you can check out this wiki, it's very well done!

[Saving and Loading Data, XmlSerializer](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer)

You would load your two UserData files like:

```
UserDataContainer UserData1 = UserDataContainer.Load(UserData1Path);
UserDataContainer UserData2 = UserDataContainer.Load(UserData2Path);
```

Later when you want to merge them you could do this:

```
// Get the contents of the first user data
List<string> CombinedDatas = UserData1.GetFields();

// Combine in the contents of the second user data
// AddRange actually changes the first list (CombinedDatas)
CombinedDatas.AddRange(UserData2.GetFields());

// If you wanted to save out the combined data in a new xml file
UserDataContainer FinalData = new UserDataContainer();
FinalData.SetFields(CombinedDatas);

FinalData.Save(FinalDataPath);
```